# How to get required attributes in object persistence model in dynamodb in .net?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

We can get the item from the dynamodb in .net as followss

var entity = await _context.LoadAsync(id);

How to get the required attributes instead of complete item?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ProjectionExpression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html) to specify which Attributes your would like to DynamoDB to retrieve for you.

Here's a [.NET example, from the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-expressions.html):

```
// using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
// using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model;

var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
var request = new GetItemRequest
{
  TableName = "YourTableName",
  ProjectionExpression = "Id, Attribute1, Attribute2",
  Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
  {
    { "Id", new AttributeValue { N = "some_value_for_id" } }
  },
};
var response = client.GetItem(request);
```